# Append table cells to select boxes in indexed order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

**I am having a huge brain fart with efficiency right now.**

The idea here is if I have a static `table` (unfortunately formatted this way with the data I've received), how would I appropriately `append` a `select option dropdown` with every value from the table categorized easily?

I currently have it working, but it seems as if I could make it more efficient than my current statement. I have the feeling with all the `DOM` manipulation I have going on, if I tried to use this on a table with **thousands** of items it would lag the browser. Let's get to the code.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/z2V2p/1/

**HTML:**

```
<table id='data'>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Prop 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Prop 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Prop 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<select id="item"></select>
<select id="value"></select>
<select id="prop"></select>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('tr td').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    var select = '<option value="'+text+'">'+text+'</option>';
    switch($this.index()){
        case 0:
          $('#item').append(select);
          break;
        case 1:
          $('#value').append(select);
          break;
        case 2:
          $('#prop').append(select);
          break;
        default:
          alert('Unexpected Error.');
     }
});
```

---

**So, I suppose the questions are:**

- Is there any easy way to make this more efficient?
- Perhaps utilizing an `array` to cache the values, and `append` them
  from that?
- Or is there an easier method of using `index` of the items instead of
  my `switch case` that would render quicker and be more expandable for further `td`s if they were implemented?

I appreciate all of the help.

**I've considered just ultimately converting the darn table to a `json` object, but I figured I'd reach out here first.**

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, wrong place? I can delete and add there. Thank you!

Comment: @moderators - Is there a problem with me linking my current discussion to this question?

Comment: As found here: [Link to beta Code Review Website](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41028/append-table-cells-to-select-boxes-in-indexed-order)